# Исправьте, пожалуйста, предложение

Tags: грамотная-речь

Исправьте, пожалуйста, предложение так чтобы оно стало более понятным.

Учитывая также тот факт, что он утверждает необходимость признания, того, что капитализм победил на земле, его труд является подлинным выражением современной мысли.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92306/discussion-on-question-by-anton------).

Comment: Вам стоит переформулировать вопрос. Хотя бы для того, чтобы формулировка в тексте соответствовала заголовку. Пока же ответ "ДА" на оба вопроса. Начинать-то так можно, но фраза настолько корявая, что даже разбирать грамматику не хочется.

Comment: @behemothus Меня полностью удовлетворил ответ Sharon. Поэтому я отметил его как принятый. Не думал, что кто-то вернется к этой теме опять...

Comment: @Василий понимаете, здесь не справочная служба (или не совсем она), вопрос может быть поднят в любое время, даже если "заказчик" давно покинул этот сервис.))) Если вам не хочется, чтобы ваш вопрос обсуждали дальше, его можно зарыть, но даже это не гарантирует.

Comment: @behemothus Я понял, спасибо. Я переформулировал вопрос. Такая формулировка годится?

Comment: @Василий я такие вещи не могу единолично решать. Мне лично не нравится слово "легковесный". Легковесный здесь воспринимается в значении "несерьезный" (фактически это сейчас основное значение). Принял бы "стало более прозрачным" (ясным, понятным)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написала так:

*Если также учесть его утверждение о необходимости признания победы капитализма на земле,  то его труд можно считать подлинным выражением современной мысли.*

Недостатки:

Деепричастный оборот употреблен некорректно. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

Синтаксис неоправданно сложный.

Comment: Но вы же любите анализировать фразу со всех сторон и писать развернутые ответы – а тут пропускаете явный криминал.